# CreateProcess with golang

Tags: go, system-calls

Hello I am try to call CreateProcess from syscall

```
func CreateProcess(appName *uint16, commandLine *uint16, procSecurity *SecurityAttributes, threadSecurity *SecurityAttributes, inheritHandles bool, creationFlags uint32, env *uint16, currentDir *uint16, startupInfo *StartupInfo, outProcInfo *ProcessInformation) (err error)
```

But I got error num 123 ("The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."), The path of the calc.exe is correct.

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var pS syscall.SecurityAttributes
    var tS syscall.SecurityAttributes
    var iH bool = true
    var cF uint32
    var env uint16
    var cD uint16
    var sI syscall.StartupInfo
    var pI syscall.ProccessInformation
    var err error

    err = syscall.CreateProcess(
        syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe"),
        syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(""),
        &pS,
        &tS,
        iH,
        cF,
        &env,
        &cD,
        &sI,
        &pI)

        fmt.Printf("Return: %d\n", err)
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using Go's higher level abstractions? Namely the `os/exec` package? https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/

Comment: After the process created I want to use with the Pointer to pI(processInformation) to write memory

Answer (score 4):

You incorrectly set parameter lpCurrentDirectory(from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> The full path to the current directory for the process. The string can
>   also specify a UNC path.
>       If this parameter is NULL, the new process will have the same current drive and directory as the calling process. (This feature is
>   provided primarily for shells that need to start an application and
>   specify its initial drive and working directory.)

If you make it nil, then it will work.
However, if to take for a sample example from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then your code can be rewritten as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    var sI syscall.StartupInfo
    var pI syscall.ProcessInformation

    argv := syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe")

    err := syscall.CreateProcess(
        nil,
        argv,
        nil,
        nil,
        true,
        0,
        nil,
        nil,
        &sI,
        &pI)

    fmt.Printf("Return: %d\n", err)
}
```